# SQL Count Entries for each Month of the last 6 Months

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I got a problem while trying to count the entries that were created in a month for the last 6 months.
The table looks like this:

```
 A       B            C               D
Year    Month    Startingdate     Identifier   
 ----------------------------------------- 
2019     3        2019-03-12      OAM_1903121  
2019     2        2019-03-21      OAM_1902211
```

And the result should look like:

```
 A       B              C               
Year    Month    Amount of orders  
--------------------------------- 
2019     3             26  
2019     2             34
```

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't get me the proper results:

```
SELECT year, month, COUNT(Startingdate) as Amount  
FROM table  
WHERE Startingdate > ((TRUNC(add_months(sysdate,-3) , 'MM'))-1)  
GROUP BY year, month
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: I'm not sure why you added the "oracle-apex" tag to this post, as it's standard SQL. Just a suggestion for your future posts.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it, but it should work:

```
select year, month, count(Stringdate) as Amount_of_order
from table
where Stringdate between add_months(sysdate, -6) and sysdate
group by year, month;
```

Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

SELECT YEAR(Startingdate) AS [Year], MONTH(Startingdate) AS [Month], COUNT(*) AS Amount
FROM table
WHERE Startingdate > DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
GROUP BY YEAR(Startingdate), MONTH(Startingdate)
ORDER BY YEAR(Startingdate), MONTH(Startingdate) DESC

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is the filtering.  If so, this should handle the most recent six full months:

```
SELECT year, month, COUNT(*) as num_orders  
FROM table  
WHERE Startingdate >= TRUNC(add_months(sysdate, -6) , 'MM')  
GROUP BY year, month;
```